# Cascade saving with Symfony and Doctrine on demand

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

I am working with two entities related by a 'one to many' relation but I'm having some problems.
Let say the entity Article has a property with a collection of Post's, and I configure the entities to use cascade. Something like that:

```
@ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Post", mappedBy="article", cascade={"remove", "persist"}, orphanRemoval=true)
```

When I try to save a instance of Article with his nested instances of Post's works fine but I don't want to save all the Post's anytime I change a property of the Article.
Seems like once you have the cascade relation defined you can only save using the cascade. Is not possible to enable and disable the cascade on demand and save a single entity without having to save all his childrens entities too?

Someone had this problem before and solved that somehow?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior. Try to use events to update/save related entities